# Color of complexes d-d transition or electron exchange

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

I always have the problem of finding whether a complex has colour due d-d transition of electrons or if it is due to electron exchange. Is there a general way to tell whether a complex has d-d transition or electron exchange? 
Is it the right method to check if a metal has d electrons and if it does. Its color must come from d-d transition and if not the color must come from charge transfer?

Comment: By electron exchange do you mean electron transfer of the form Fe(II) to Fe(III) for example?

Comment: No.. From metal to ligand or from ligand to metal.

Comment: That's usually called "charge transfer" not "electron exchange" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-transfer_complex#Inorganic_charge-transfer_complexes

Comment: in which case d-d transitions are usually weak and at long wavelength, metal-ligand transitions are usually more intense and may swamp d-d in some cases. But there is no hard and fast rule, you have to study each case carefully.

Comment: So if I'm given a complex compound. I would have to check if it has d-electrons or not and find out if d-d transition is taking place?